# Cannot get or create PersistentEntity for type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to expose some services through the Spring `JPARepository` interface
So I created a StudentRepo like this:

```
package edu.university.management.dao;

import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

import edu.university.management.model.Student;
import edu.university.management.model.StudentsPerDepartment;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    
    @RestResource(path = "/byDeptOrdered")
    //@Query("select s from Student s where s.department.name = 'Informatique' order by s.entryDate desc")
    public List<Student> findByDepartment_NameOrderByEntryDateDesc(String deptName);
    
    
    @RestResource(path = "/topStudents")
    @Query("select s"
            + " from Student s"
            + " where s.mark = ("
                + "select max(s.mark)"
                + " from Student s"
            + ")")
    public List<Student> topStudents();
    
    @RestResource(path = "/studentsPerDept")
    @Query("select new edu.university.management.model.StudentsPerDepartment(d.name, count(s))"
            + " from Department d"
            + " left join"
            + " d.students s"
            + " group by d.name")
    public List<StudentsPerDepartment> studentCountPerDepartment();
}
```

For the last service `studentCountPerDepartment` I used a class based `projection` to avoid returning an `array` of Objects,

StudentsPerDepartment:

```
package edu.university.management.model;


public class StudentsPerDepartment {

    private String departmentName;
    private Long studentCount;
    
    public StudentsPerDepartment(String departmentName, Long studentCount) {
        super();
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
        this.studentCount = studentCount;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public Long getStudentCount() {
        return studentCount;
    }

}
```

But when i invoke the service i get this error:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot get or create PersistentEntity for type edu.university.management.model.StudentsPerDepartment! PersistentEntities knows about 2 MappingContext instances and therefore cannot identify a single responsible one. Please configure the initialEntitySet through an entity scan using the base package in your configuration to pre initialize contexts.
```

Any ideas guys?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you have in class  `Department`? It's mapped right? or try to add an attr in your count like this `select new edu.university.management.model.StudentsPerDepartment( d.name,  count( s.{ANY_ATTR_TO_COUNT_FROM_DEPARTMENT} ) )`.... Or try add package referencie into `Department` like `from some.package.Department d`

Comment: @DilermandoLima yes class `Department` is mapped and it only has two fields {`id`, `name`}, and i also tried to replace the object with an attribute in the count like this: `select new edu.university.management.model.StudentsPerDepartment(d.name, count(s.id))` but still without luck